# With index, open(file) as enumerate(filepointer)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to open a file using the `with` syntax while also enumerating the file's lines.

So I tried this:

```
with index, open(filename) as enumerate(f):
    f.read()...
```

Where `f` is meant to correspond to `open(filename)`, and `index` should take `enumerate(f)`. So I want to be able to call `f.read()` in the body, and know which line of the file is being processed.

I'm sure this can be done -- I'm just not using the syntax correctly. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the closest thing that's valid Python to what you're trying is this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        # Do stuff with each line.
```

`f.read()` reads the entire contents of `f` and stores it in a string, so you wouldn't be able to get line numbers that way.

You can't combine the `enumerate` call with the `with` statement because the [language's grammar just doesn't allow it](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

> ```
> with_stmt ::=  "with" with_item ("," with_item)* ":" suite
> with_item ::=  expression ["as" target]
> ```
>
> The execution of the with statement with one “item” proceeds as
>   follows:
>
> 1. The context expression (the expression given in the with_item) is
>      evaluated to obtain a context manager.
> 2. The context manager’s `__exit__()` is loaded for later use.
> 3. The context manager’s `__enter__()` method is invoked.
> 4. **If a `target` was included in the with statement, the return value from
>      `__enter__()` is assigned to it.**

`target` is meant to be a variable that the return value of `open(filename)` is assigned to. It can't be a function call.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing the `with` statement with the `for` statement. In

```
for i, x in enumerate(lst):
```

`i` and `x` are set to the values obtained from the iterator created by `enumerate`. In

```
with open(filename) as f:
```

`f` is assigned the return value of `open`.

You cannot mix the two. You need to use two separate statements:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
```